# (FileNotFoundException) - Referencing the Nuget instead of dll in ReferenceAssemblies folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have an asp.net project targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2. And it throws
the following error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

I have `System.IO.Compression.4.3.0` installed as a Nuget due to a dependency to another Nuget package. As a result, I have the following configuration in my csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.1.2.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, 
processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.Compression.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.IO.Compression.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

and the following binding redirect in web.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

But when I look at the References node of the project, I see that the path of the reference is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.IO.Compression.dll`.
And it is true that there is no such dll inside the bin folder.

How can I make it use the Nuget package instead of the dll in the .NETFramework folder?

Comment: Maybe <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />